# How to run Ansible without hosts file

Tags: shell, ansible

How to run Ansible without hosts file?

just like:

```
$ ansible --"Some Options" IP  -a 'uptime'
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
ansible all -i "<hostname-or-ip>," -a 'uptime'
```

Note the `,` at the end of the IP address, or it will be considered a hosts inventory filename.

Here is an example for reference:

```
ansible all -i "192.168.33.100," -a 'uptime'

192.168.33.100 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
 12:05:10 up 10 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.46, 0.23, 0.08
```

Comment: That bloody comma cost me 10 minutes...Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

Hosts can be given to ansible using three ways

- Using inventory path in ansible.cfg which is /etc/ansible/host by default
- Using hosts file

  ```
   ansible -i /tmp/hosts -a 'uptime' all
  ```
- Using hosts ip as comma separated host list. **Take care of the comma in the end of the list**

  ```
   ansible -i "192.168.1.16,192.168.1.80:2222," -a 'uptime' all
  ```

From `ansible --help` you can get `-i` option description

```
-i INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                    specify inventory host path
                    (default=/etc/ansible/hosts) or comma separated host
                    list.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want run playbook at once or some more and not whole list, you can try with -l|--limit "your.node.local"

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.hosts --limit your.node.local user.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers here have most of what you need but in order to SSH to a remote host you need to tell `ansible` what user to SSH as, especially if it's different on the system you're running `ansible` from and the remote targets.

For example, I have 4 RPi4 systems with Ubuntu 20.04 on them. To access them with an Ansiible ad-hoc command:

```
$ ansible -i "k8s-02a,k8s-02b,k8s-02c,pi-vpn," -a uptime all -u ubuntu
pi-vpn | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
 12:47:26 up  7:52,  1 user,  load average: 0.14, 0.14, 0.10
k8s-02c | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
 12:47:27 up  7:58,  1 user,  load average: 0.06, 0.10, 0.09
k8s-02a | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
 12:47:27 up  7:58,  1 user,  load average: 0.43, 0.50, 0.47
k8s-02b | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
 12:47:27 up  7:58,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.06, 0.04
```

Here I'm providing a list of my hostnames to -`i` and also directing `ansible` to use the username `ubuntu`.

**NOTE:** My `ansible` version:

```
$ ansible --version | grep ^ans
ansible 2.9.11
```